# a NaN output in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nan

I have a problem in JS that really burns in my soul!!
I want to create a program that prompt the user to inter his name then his hourly wage then how many hours he has worked for?
like:
Enter your name please: Saleh
Enter your hourly wage: 20
Enter the worked hours: 8

I need this program to print a message that says:
Hello Saleh
Your hourly wage is: 20 $
You have worked for: 8 hours
Your payment is: 160 $

the program that i have made is working but the last line isn't giving any calculation! it prints NaN !!

Please help me

here's the code:

```js
function Worker(aName, anHourlyWage, numberOfHours) // initializing the worker function that asked in the question.
{
  this.name = aName;
  this.anHourlyWage = anHourlyWage;
  this.numberOfHours = numberOfHours;

  this.setHourlyWage = setHourlyWage;
  this.getName = getName;
  this.getHourlyWage = getHourlyWage;
  this.getHours = getHours;
  this.calculatePayment = calculatePayment;
  this.printDetails = printDetails;


}

function setHourlyWage(setHourlyWage) {
  this.anHourlyWage = anHourlyWage2;
}

function getName() {
  return this.name;
}

function getHourlyWage() {
  return this.anHourlyWage;
}

function getHours() {
  return this.numberOfHours;
}

function calculatePayment() {
  return this.getHourlyWage * this.getHours; //to return the multiplication of working hours function and  hourly wage function
}

function printDetails() {
  window.alert("Hello: " + this.getName() +
               "\n Your Wage Is: " + this.getHourlyWage() +
               " $" + "\n You Have Worked For: " + this.getHours() + " Hours" +
               "\n Your Payment Is: " + this.calculatePayment() + " $");
}


var name1 = window.prompt("Enter your name:", "");
var anHourlyWage1 = parseFloat(window.prompt("Enter the Hourly Wage:"));
var numberOfHours1 = parseFloat(window.prompt("Enetr the working hours:"));

var Worker1 = new Worker(name1, anHourlyWage1, numberOfHours1);
Worker1.printDetails();
```

Comment: what do you think `this` is in `setHourlyWage`, `getName` etc?

Comment: @JaromandaX - It's the right object, isn't it, as set by the initial `Worker1.printDetails()` call?

Comment: yes, so it is. Never seen it done that way before. Ugly

Comment: @JaromandaX—it's like prototype inheritance without the prototype. Or inheritance… ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your `calculatePayment()` function you are not calling the `getHourlyWage()` and `getHours()` functions and multiplying their return values, you are multiplying references to the functions themselves.

Change this line:

```
return this.getHourlyWage * this.getHours;
```

to this:

```
return this.getHourlyWage() * this.getHours();
```

(Note the added parentheses.)

Comment: I think this falls in the category of typo, so voted to close too.